# VBA - Range.Copy Method Error on Table with User-Defined Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've come across a fairly weird issue and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is an Excel bug (using Excel 2010 for PC, BTW)... To explain, let me create a simple scenario:

1. I define a very simple UDF that uses properties of a Range object, for example:

   ```
   Public Function SillyThing(rng As Range) As Variant
       SillyThing = rng.IndentLevel
   End Function
   ```
2. I have a simple table defined in my workbook (`Table1`, say) with only one row at the start:

   ```
   Col1:      Col2:
   <blank>    =SillyThing([@col1])
   ```
3. I have a column of cells in, say, `Range("F2:F8")`
4. I have the following `Sub` defined:

   ```
   Sub Macro3()
       Range("F2:F8").Copy Range("Table1[col1]")
   End Sub
   ```

Now, when I run that macro, it gives me `#VALUE!` error for the entire second column in my table (where the formula would get auto-filled).

However, if I use the following macro instead:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("F2:F8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Table1[col1]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Then it works just fine!

Upon debugging, if I place a breakpoint in the UDF, I find that the `Range` object passed through in `Macro3` has the following statement for **many** of its properties - `: IndentLevel : <Unable to get the IndentLevel property of the Range class> : Variant : Module1.SillyThing`

Obviously, I know how to fix it using the same idea as `Macro2`, but I'm really curious if this is a known issue or if there's something I'm missing / other workarounds I'm unfamiliar with.

Hope this makes sense!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the same thing as you do.

> but I'm really curious if this is a known issue or if there's something I'm missing / other workarounds I'm unfamiliar with.

Not sure if it is a known issue, it certainly seems counter-intuitive. Why would it not work???  If I had to venture a guess, it's a bug. There is a known limitation of UDF's when called *from the worksheet*, that they cannot access some properties and cannot interact with other ranges that were not passed as an argument to the function itself, etc. But in this case the only range being accessed is the one passed as an argument to the function itself, so that doesn't even really make sense, but it's the first thing I think of.

Even though that explanation doesn't make sense... if I do this, the function errors at the `ret = ...` line:

```
Public Function SillyThing(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim ret As Variant
    ret = rng.IndentLevel
    SillyThing = ret
End Function
```

I even tried this evaluating the range address indentlevel like `[A2].indentLevel` which raised the same error.  The range *does* exist, and it's not a multi-cell range (which might be expected to raise an error).

However, if I do this instead, **the function doesn't error** and the table updates with the copy/paste:

```
Public Function SillyThing(rng As Range) As Variant

    SillyThing = rng & " 1"
End Function
```

**So it certainly seems related to some inadvertent limitation that is preventing you from accessing the `.IndentLevel` property of the range argument.**

But here is another slightly more elegant workaround: Instead of Macro2, try this -- at least better than using Select method :)

```
Range("Table1[Col2]").Copy  'Or Range("F2:F8").Copy - both seem to work the same
Range("Table1[Col1]").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

And this method should also work:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Range("E2:E5").Copy Range("Table1[Code]")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculate
```

Comment: Thanks, David, that is EXACTLY the workaround I had ended up using - Like I stated in the question, it wasn't that I didn't know how to fix it, rather that it was a weird bug / quirk... It does make me happy to hear that it wasn't just something I was doing stupidly wrong... I'm going to leave the question open for a few more days **hoping** some else has knowledge of this, otherwise, I'll makr yours as the solution... Thanks for taking the time to check out the question!